# ArrayList NullPointerException to ORMLite saving

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, ormlite

I have an class Category

```
  @DatabaseTable(tableName = "categories")
public class Category {
    public final static String CATEGORY_TITLE_FIELD_NAME  = "title";
    @SerializedName("id")
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    int id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.STRING, columnName = CATEGORY_TITLE_FIELD_NAME)
    String title;
    // need for ORMlite
    public Category()
    {}
    public Category (int id, String title)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public int getCategoryId() 
    {

         return this.id;
    }

    public String getCategoryTitle() 
    {
         return this.title;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int id)
    {
         this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCategoryTitle(String title)
    {
         this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {       
    return "{title="+title +" "+"id="+id+"}";   
    }

}
```

And I put data to it from JSON and want to save it in the ORMLite. This is how I do it:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject(KEY_DATA);
// getting categories
JSONArray categories = new JSONArray();
categories = data.getJSONArray(KEY_CATEGORIES);
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray array = parser.parse(categories.toString()).getAsJsonArray();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Category>>() {}.getType();
List<Category> tasks = new ArrayList<Category>();
tasks = gson.fromJson(array.toString(), listType);
RuntimeExceptionDao<Category, Integer> simpleDao = getHelper1().getSimpleCategoryDao();
Dao<Category, Integer> categoryDao = getHelper1().getCategoryDao();
saveContacts(tasks);
List<Category> list = categoryDao.queryForAll();
Log.i("categoryDAO",list.toString());
```

And this is saveContacts() method for data saving:

```
 public void saveContacts(List<Category> contacts) throws SQLException
    {
        OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper dbHelper= DatabaseHandler.getInstance(_context);
        Dao<Category, Integer> daoContact=dbHelper.getDao(Category.class);
        for (Category contact : contacts) {
            daoContact.create(contact);
        }
        dbHelper.close();
    }
```

But I've got such exception as:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:63)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.create(BaseDaoImpl.java:304)
    at com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity.saveContacts(LoginActivity.java:192)
    at com.assignmentexpert.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:108)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please, tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORMLite can't create second table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737214/ormlite-cant-create-second-table)

Comment: Posting your entire program again to debug your next problem is just wasting the communities time.

Comment: I'm sorry for this. But I tried different ways to solve it and  need a little hint. I put my json parsing and saving it in the ORMLite at the separate class. Call this method in the onCreate(...) method of the DatabaseHandler class. But I still getting exception above...Appreciate your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved passing context to my DatabaseHandler that extends from OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.